# How to enter values instead of using static values in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to enter the values of "cell1" and "cell2" dynamically in the table instead of using the static values "one" and "two".
How to do it?

```
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(4);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);


    //cell2 = document.getElementById('cell2');
    cell1.innerHTML = "One";
    cell2.innerHTML = "two";
}
```

Comment: Where do you expect to get the values from?

Comment: your code is working fine. What is the exact problem

Comment: from where you are getting dynamic values?

Comment: @brk OP wants a generic way where he/she can create a table of `m*n` cells with value as index value but in words

Comment: @Rajesh - are you clairvoyant? How do you get all that from the paltry code posted?

Comment: @JaromandaX No sir. Just a dumb dev, but I assumed based on words like `instead of using the static values` and values like `"one", "two"`

Comment: it's all good @Rajesh - "dumb dev" I like it

Comment: Replace `"one"` and `"two"` with [**variables**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Variable) containing the values you want to insert. By the way, it is preferable to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` (unless you are really inserting HTML)`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are just starting to learn JS, then may be what you are looking for is `prompt`

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(4);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);



    //cell2 = document.getElementById('cell2');
    var one, two;
    one = prompt("Please enter first value");
    two = prompt("Please enter second value");
    cell1.innerHTML = one;
    cell2.innerHTML = two;
}
</script>
```

However, this is not how things are done in real solutions to real world problems.